# export treetable primefaces to pdf

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I want to export a treetable(primefaces) to Pdf
What should I do.
 I added primefaces extensions, but I got this message

> Tag Library supports namespace:
>   http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions, but no tag was defined for name:
>   dataExporter

Thanks for your reponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PrimeFaces extensions it is called [`pe:exporter`](http://primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/exporter.jsf). In PrimeFaces itself it is a [`p:dataExporter`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml). So you use the wrong combination of namespace(-prefix) and tag name by using `pe:dataExporter`